# Error "DBCC execution completed" when running data connection from Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I get this error when I try to run this data connection from Excel 2010

Connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Data Source=sql-
server;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet
Size=4096;Workstation ID=PV-SAMSUNG;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with
column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=BVR_AUTOMAX
```

Command text:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'
BEGIN
DBCC TRACEON(8765);
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(SugarCRM, ''
select ticker_symbol,count(a.id) as pocet,sum(case when     ifnull(a.account_erp_id,0)=''''0'''' then 0 else 1 end) as bvr, count(a.id) -  sum(case when ifnull(a.account_erp_id,0)=''''0'''' then 0 else 1 end) as delta
from crm.accounts a inner join crm.users u on a.assigned_user_id=u.id
inner join crm.accounts_cstm ac on a.id=ac.id_c
where a.deleted=0
group by ticker_symbol 
having delta>0 and bvr>0
order by delta desc;
'' );
END';
```

When I run this code in MS SQL Server Mngt Studio it works fine.
Thanks for your help
Petr

Comment: OK, I just figured out that if I remove the _DBCC TRACEON(8765)_ from the code in SQL command in Excel it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, quite simple one. Just change this line of code to the following (add the WITH NO_INFOMSGS argument)

```
 DBCC TRACEON(8765)  WITH NO_INFOMSGS ;
```